# Why ListItem content not showing anything

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

[image]

```
import {Avatar, ListItem} from 'react-native-elements';

 <View style={{flex: 3}}>
      <ListItem
        key="live-jobs"
        title="Live Jobs"
        textStyle={{color: 'orange'}}
        leftIcon={
          <Icon name="access-point" size={25} style={{color: '#4BC6FF'}} />
        }
        onPress={() =>
          this.checkPermissions(LIVE_JOB_END_POINT, 'liveJobs')
        }
      />
      <Text>Hiiii</Text>
      <ListItem
        key="notifications"
        title="Notifications"
        leftIcon={
          <Icon name="bell-ring" size={25} style={{color: '#4BC6FF'}} />
        }
        onPress={() => Actions.userManagement()}
      />
</View>
```

My React-native version is 0.64.2 ,React native elements version 3.4.2 Why does the content inside the ListItem  Not display anything?

Comment: i don't know much about react native (but i know react) question, how are you importing the Icon component?

Comment: @laserany import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

Comment: I'm not seeing that in the code? would you share the full snippet? i am looking at the documentation here https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/listitem/ and it seems the way you implement the listItem is different? example they had was https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/listitem/#using-map-function---implemented-with-link-and-icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  <ListItem key="live-jobs" bottomDivider>
    <Avatar source={{uri: l.avatar_url}} />
    <ListItem.Content>
      <ListItem.Title>Live Jobs</ListItem.Title>
      <ListItem.Subtitle>Subtitle</ListItem.Subtitle>
    </ListItem.Content>
  </ListItem>
```